# .NET Core 2.0 accessing user secrets

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm trying to setup a .net core 2.0 web application to send an email when user registers and also to recover password. I have followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?tabs=visual-studio.

However, upon reading the comments sections, it seems that the tutorial is not updated for Core 2.0. My question is, when I get to part "*Add the user secrets configuration source to the Startup method*", I cannot figure out how the startup file should look like since my startup file is different from the one showed there. Can anyone help me by showing me how the startup file should look like? Thanks.

This is my current startup file:

```
public class Startup
{
    string _testSecret = null;

    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _testSecret = Configuration["MySecret"];
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
        {
            config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
        })
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        services.AddMvc();
        services.Configure<AuthMessageSenderOptions>(Configuration);
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code I didn't find invoking of build() function of ConfigurationBuilder class. Here is the sample code.

```
var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
builder.AddUserSecrets<Startup>();
var config builder.Build(); //This line is missing from your code
string mySecret = config ['EmailAccount'];
```

Refernce: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/app-secrets?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=windows#access-a-secret